# How to reuse the same content on different sections of an installed WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, categories, bulk

I am building a freelancing marketplace using Exertio Theme on WordPress.
The theme provide sections to edit details of the freelancers, employers and to manage projects and services from the backend.
Since some details like projects and services categories, skills, languages and others need to be added one by one for each section, I was wondering if there is a way to do this more quickily at once in a bulk ?

[image: Here is an exemple]

Thanks for your help

I am adding categories, skills, locations and languages one by one and it's time consuming